# How can i know the modifyEvent is snapped or not

Tags: openlayers

I am using Modify and Snap interaction together, I am listening the `modifyEnd` event of the Modify interaction. How can i know the modifyEvent is snapped or not.

Snap interaction does not work well with 3D geometries. My geometries are 3D. `Z` value is not changing even snapped vertex `Z` is different. So how can i get the vertex of the snapped position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.getEventPixel(event.mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent)` will be the true position of the pointer.

`event.mapBrowserEvent.pixel` will the the snapped position.

If they are different the position has been updated by the Snap interaction.

Also if snapped `event.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate` will be a point exactly on the snapped geometry while `map.getCoordinateFromPixel(event.mapBrowserEvent.pixel)` will be a less accurate coordinate calculated to one pixel accuracy

Comment: I detailed my question, can you help me more :)

Comment: I think modify/snap would only be designed to work in 2d on a flat screen.  You could interpolate between the existing vertices to set an appropriate z.for a new point.

Comment: I made an app like proof of concept app. you guys can check that over [here](https://github.com/feyzullahyildiz/openlayers-multisnap-test)